# Erro em busca no Banco de dados

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados

Minha aplicação está integrada ao meu banco e efetua diversas consultas, porém em uma delas está acontecendo algo inesperado, pois a busca não é efetuada.

Notem que a minha linha de instrução é simples e está correta (funciona quando executo manualmente no MySql, por exemplo.

Outro fato é que se troco a variável "aero" por "LAS" - que é um dos valores do banco - a busca ocorre normalmente.

Coloquei aquelas 3 mensagens de teste para saber até onde ele está indo e a única que não executa é "Teste 3", ou seja, por algum motivo não vai além do `rs = stmt.executeQuery();`

Não creio ser a variável "Aero" o problema, pois ela está passando certinho (já testei printando a mesma) e o rs `= stmt.executeQuery();` está igual aos outros métodos que funcionam corretamente.

Enfim, já li e reli o código algumas vezes e não descubro o que pode ser.

Segue o código:

```
 public List<Dados> buscarAero(String aero, boolean check1, boolean check2) {

    Connection con = ConnectionDB.getConnection(); 
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    List<Dados> dados = new ArrayList<>(); 

    if (check1 && !check2) { 

        try {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("teste 1");

            stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `2008` WHERE Origin = " + aero);

            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("teste 2");

            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("teste 3");

            while (rs.next()) {    
                Dados info = new Dados();

                info.setFlightNum(rs.getInt("FlightNum"));
                info.setOrigin(rs.getString("Origin"));
                info.setDest(rs.getString("Dest"));

                dados.add(info);       
}
```

Comment: Não poste imagem do código, poste-o diretamente na pergunta.

Comment: @diegofm editei. Favor remover o voto negativo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessário circundar o valor de `aero` em aspas simples, que é como o MySQL vai entender que isto é uma string literal e não algum identificador.

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `2008` WHERE Origin = '" + aero + "'");
```

Comment: Perfeito @jbueno. Obrigado